# Python pynput failed to acquire x connection

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtual-machine, mouse, pynput

Im getting the error 'failed to acquire X connection: cant't connect to display ":0": No protocol specified\n'

`echo $DISPLAY` results in `:0`

I've tried $ `DISPLAY=:0 python -c 'import pynput'`

I'm running ubuntu in virtual box on a win10 machine trying to control mouse movements via python.

any help would be greatly apprectiated, kinda hit a wall.